# Django - Variable deleting itself prior to Object Create?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

Consider this **snippet**:

```
if fire_prim is not None:
    print('Fire Primary is definitely not Null, here is proof: {}'.format(fire_prim))
    fire_primary_obj = LifeSafety.objects.create(
        name='Fire Primary', 
        store=store_obj, 
        phone_line=fire_prim, 
        phone_line_provider=an_provider)
```

We get the following **output**:

```
Fire Primary is definitely not Null, here is proof: +16077244546
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: stores_lifesafety.phone_line

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin-dksc104694\Desktop\Dev\it-database\scripts\data.py", line 246, in update_lifesafety_devices
    fire_primary_obj = LifeSafety.objects.create(name='Fire Primary', store=store_obj, phone_line=fire_prim, phone_line_provider=an_provider)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 413, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 718, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 748, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 831, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 869, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1136, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: stores_lifesafety.phone_line
```

We can see with 100% certainty that the line just before object creation, `fire_prim` has a value of `+16077244546` which should serve as the `phone_line`, but by the time it gets to creation its deleted somehow.

Here is my **model** for reference:

```
class LifeSafety(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='unspecified')
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    phone_line = PhoneNumberField()
    phone_line_provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    last_verification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Pre-Question:**

- I've allowed **Null** on the object and left the code to run &
  unsurprisingly the objects are created, but `phone_line` is blank.
- I am using the [PhoneNumberField](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) library.
- I can "mock" this exact code from the shell & the object is created with the correct value every time.
- The snippet above is exactly as shown, there is nothing in between the printing of `fire_prim` & the attempt at creation.

---

**Post-Question:**

- Changed `phone_line` to a **CharField** rather than **PhoneNumberField** & the phone number is going through just fine. I'm opening an issue on their [Github Repo](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) as well.
- Explicitly used the string as `phone_line` when creating the instance.
- Verified once more that this can be done from shell without issue.

  **Input:** LifeSafety.objects.create(name='Fire Primary', store=store, phone_line='+16077244546')

  **Output:** LifeSafety: Fire Primary (Indicating QuerySet)

---

Interestingly when I do use the string explicitly on creation, the object does create with `phone_line` populated with that string, but I still get the error.

**Input:**

```
    print('Fire Primary is definitely not Null, here is proof: {}'.format(fire_prim))

    fire_primary_obj = LifeSafety.objects.create(
        name = 'Fire Primary', 
        store = store_obj, 
        phone_line = '+16077244546', 
        phone_line_provider = an_provider
    )
```

**Output** is the same stack trace as above (only name differences in diff checker).

I can go into admin and see that it was created, but I still get the `NOT NULL constraint` exception.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, in your model, your import statement looks something like `from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField`, correct? I know that the django-phonenumber-field plugin also has a `PhoneNumberField` in other modules as well (e.g., form and serializer).

Comment: Is `+16077244546` a valid value for a `PhoneNumberField`?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions. I can copy & paste this in the shell & get exactly what's expected, but running from this script fails. I'll post some more details about my environment when I get back to my desk.

Comment: @CodeSpent can you try passing something like `PhoneNumberField("+16077244546")` instance. Instead of string

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari see above edit in Post-Question. This works, but it still raises the exception. I could catch it & move on, but I don't want to do that.